# Download PrestaShop PDF invoice using web service

Tags: php, web-services, prestashop

I would like to download (or just obtain the contents of) the PDF file of an order's invoice on PrestaShop 1.6 and 1.7, using the [web service](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Web+service+one-page+documentation), but it does'nt seem possible.

I specify that I don't have access to the PrestaShop website code, and that I can't install any module ; and I'm currently using PHP to do my API calls.

Would anyone have a solution for me?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider to make a simple endpoint within a module (you can generate a structure easely here : https://validator.prestashop.com) as there is no internal solution provided.

Just make a frontend controller or use the (too complex compared to the previous one) solution provided here : [Extend prestashop webservice resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37996663/extend-prestashop-webservice-resource)