# PrestaShop - calling module methods from Vue.js back office application

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I'm working on PrestaShop module. I have Vue.js app which is running in the backoffice, and I want to make an http request to my module class in order to populate some data. How can this be achieved?

I want to be able to simply expose some kind of API, or call php method in some way.

I was able to expose some API endpoints to FrontEnd of module using custom fronts controllers, but I have no idea how to make this work in backoffice. Any help would highly valuable for me, thanks!

Comment: Never did this but PrestaShop has its own webService classes you can possible expand upon in your module: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37996663/extend-prestashop-webservice-resource  https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/1027248-extend-prestashop-webservice/#comment-3248756

Comment: Thanks for good resources, I will give them a try!

Answer (score 1):

Like for the Front office, you can create controllers inside the Back office. Here's a page from the developer documentation:
https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/controllers/admin-controllers/

Make sure to check some of the examples from the native modules:
https://github.com/PrestaShop/blockwishlist/blob/dev/src/Controller/WishlistConfigurationAdminController.php

https://github.com/PrestaShop/example-modules/tree/master/democontrollertabs

Comment: Would it be possible to use a front controller and make them accessible only from back office? I find them more developer friendly.

Comment: You can do that, you can link to your `ModuleFrontController` from back office :) make sure to properly protect your endpoint if it is needed